# OpenCV hello world not compiling like it should

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am setting up a new machine with OpenCV 2.3.1.  The machine is a Windows 7 box, and I followed the installation instructions given by the OpenCV website (used CMake with MinGW to build).

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
int main() {
    char var;
    cv::Mat img;
    img = cv::imread("C:/test/img.jpg");
    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image", img);
    std::cin >> var;
    return 1;
}
```

Here is my make command:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy
```

Here is my path:

```
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\install\bin;C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\install\include;C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin;C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin;
```

Here is my error:

```
main.cpp:2:33: error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp:3:39: error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8: error: 'cv' has not been declared
main.cpp:8: error: expected ';' before 'img'
main.cpp:9: error: 'img' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:9: error: 'cv' has not been declared
main.cpp:10: error: 'cv' has not been declared
main.cpp:11: error: 'cv' has not been declared
```

This is not making sense.  Why won't this compile?  Why can't it find opencv2/core/core.hpp?

Comment: Could you post a link to instruction you followed?

Answer (score 2):

`g++` doesn't consider `%PATH%` (`$PATH` on Unix) when looking for include files.

Add the following to the compilation command: `-IC:\OpenCV-2.3.1\install\include`:

```
g++ -IC:\OpenCV-2.3.1\install\include -o main main.cpp -lopencv_core ...
```

Comment: This is moreso troubleshooting for QT creator not compiling correctly... Same issue there?

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the right OpenCV directories.

I made an installation of a previous version of OpenCV in `C:\OpenCV2.3`, and these are the paths I had to add for my compiler to find the headers:

```
C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv

C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include\opencv2

C:\OpenCV2.3\build\include
```

Traditionally, **g++** takes headers directories with the `-I`  flag, which you doesn't seem to be using at all.

Answer (score 0):

on unix like os

```
     g++ filename.cpp -o exec `pkg-config opencv cvblob --libs --cflags`
```

(cvblob optional if you are checking for blob)